# How to check file is accessible?

Tags: excel, vba

My test sub doesn't seem to work when there is an unconnected direct network link (\server\name\file.txt) involved.

> Runtime error 52, bad filename or number.

The folder is not mapped on some computers. Is there a way to check or a way around this?

Seems to work if I use the mapped network drive on its own.

```
Sub Example()

Dim netPath, mapPath as String

netPath = "\\server\name\file.txt"
mapPath = "H:\name\file.txt"

If Len(Dir(netPath, vbDirectory)) > 0 Or Len(Dir(mapPath, vbDirectory)) > 0 Then
    GoTo Continue
Else
    rspn = MsgBox("Error", vbCritical, "Error")
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    If Workbooks.Count > 1 Then
        ThisWorkbook.Close
    Else
        Application.Quit
    End If
    Exit Sub
End If

Continue:
'My normal code here

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Dir()` method throws an error if the parent folder/drive does not exist.

Use the `FileSystemObject` to check if the file exist. It doesn't throw an error, but simply returns false if it doesn't.

```
With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If .FileExists(filepath) Then '...
End With
```